# How do I add Hyperlinks to usage text?

Tags: usage-messages, hyperlink

I want to include a Hyperlink inside of a `usage`.  For example:

```
function::usage = "function[x] does a complicated calculation
  following the algorithms in this paper."
```

where "this paper" is hyperlinked to a paper on the web.

To get an idea for how the boxes works for `Hyperlinks`, I did:

```
Hyperlink["here", "paclet:ref/Plot"] // ToBoxes
```

> TagBox[ButtonBox[PaneSelectorBox[{False->"here", True->StyleBox["here", {HyperlinkActive}]}, False, BaseStyle->{Hyperlink}, FrameMargins->0, ImageSize->Automatic], BaseStyle->Link, ButtonData->paclet:ref/Plot, ButtonNote->paclet:ref/Plot], #1&]

That was a lot of boxes to put into the usage string:

```
function::usage = "function[x] does a complicated calculation
  following the algorithms in 
  \!\(\*TagBox[\(\*ButtonBox[\(\*PaneSelectorBox[]\),y]\),y]\)"
```

I got overwhelmed with all the `\(\* \)`'s so I gave up.

Is there a better way to include hyperlinks inside of usage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually do it this way:

```
f::usage =
        ToString[Row[{
                      Style["f[ _Integer ]", Bold], " maps ", 
                      Style[Hyperlink["integer", "paclet:ref/Integer"], Italic], 
                      " to real number."
                     }], StandardForm];

?f
```

[image: formated usage text]

Comment: Haven't seen you for some days!:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Am kind of busy recently :)

Answer (score 4):

Just evaluate your hyperlink code:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then copy the hyperlink from the output and paste it in your string

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The boxes were worked into your string automatically:

[image: Mathematica graphics]